# Why do I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" of my CSS file in Django?

Tags: css, django

So I have this Django application perfectly working in Ubuntu server, but keep getting the error above. WHAT'S REALLY STRANGE is that it started to fail loading at some point. So (though this may be a vague expression) the upper part of my css file, which was written some time ago is well-applied to the page. However from some point in the file, nothing is applied and I started to get the error. Let me show you the code. 
 everyday.css

```
#today {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.keywordInputs {
    width: 125px;
    background-color: #f6f5f1;
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
}
.keywordInputs:focus{
    background-color: #f6f5f1;
    border: #9300d3 solid 1px;
}
.kw12 {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.everyday-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.img-col {
    padding: 2.5px;
}
.calendar-img {
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}
```

So in the code above, when the page is loaded, the settings up until `.kw12` is applied, but the rest down below isn't. 
I swear the path is 100% correct, I've done `python manage.py collectstatic` command, but I keep getting the error. What do you think is the problem?
For your info, this is my template.

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/base.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/everyday.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
...
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: show your folder structure

Comment: what does devtools say?

Answer (score -1):

The error is in your CSS file. You did not declare the `border` property for `.keywordInputs:focus{}` correctly. It should be as below:

```css
.keywordInputs:focus{
    background-color: #f6f5f1;
    border: 1px solid #9300d3;
}
```